# Display the same page after saving 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like show a form with some field (one in the example), submit it, save and display the same page with a reset of all fields. The probelm when I submit, I go the "Save" action but when I display the view the form is still filled in.

**The model :**

```
public class TestingModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**The controller :**

```
    public class ChildController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TestingModel model = new TestingModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Save(TestingModel model)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(model.FirstName); //OK

        //Save data to DB here ...          

        TestingModel testingModel = new TestingModel() { FirstName = string.Empty };
        return View("Index", testingModel);
    }
}
```

**The view :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Child",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.FirstName)
   <input type="submit" id="btSave" />
}
```

When Id debug to the view, in "Immediat window" `Model.FirstName = ""` but when the page is show I still have the value posted. I tried a `ReditrectionToAction("Index")` at the end of the `Save` method but same result.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to do this you need to clear everything that's in the ModelState. Otherwise HTML helpers will completely ignore your model and use data from ModelState when binding their values.

Like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(TestingModel model)
{
    //Save data to DB here ...          

    ModelState.Clear();
    TestingModel testingModel = new TestingModel() { FirstName = string.Empty };
    return View("Index", testingModel);
}
```

or simply redirect to the Index `GET` action in case of success:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(TestingModel model)
{
    //Save data to DB here ...          
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin :) My sample is working, trying now in the real project, stay tuned :)

Comment: @Kris-l that will definitely work in real project. The ModelState has the highest priority of providers of values for model. When you post model for the first time, ModelState gets populated with your posted values. Then, no matter if you supply the new() model to you view, or supply null value, ModelState already contains values from  your previously posted model, and it populates the new model with those values(highest priority). So you get the same model values in your view. But when you clear modelstate and pass the new() model to view, you truly get the newly valued model.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return `Index` view without any model

```
  return View("Index");
```

Comment: did you cache the view? or may be your browser do

Comment: Not a browser cache trouble, I tried on Firefox (using Chrome in general) same result.

Answer (score 0):

You should be posting your form back to the same `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TestingModel model = new TestingModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TestingModel model)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(model.FirstName); //OK

        //Save data to DB here ...          


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

You would be able to use the parameterless overload for `BeginForm` too

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   //form
}
```