# Entity Framework : Incorrect result in child collections when repeat queries

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity framework.
I have this scenario :

**ParentObject** - has a child collection : **Child1**.

On the Form I have 1 checkbox and 1 button.
I have a report that display the PArentObject and the corresponding list of Child1.

the Onclick's event  of the button  has this code :

---

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
Dim plist as IQueryable(Of ParentObject)
Dim chlist as IQueryable(of Child1)
plist=context.Set(Of ParentObject)
chlist=context.Set(of Child1)

plist.ToList()
chlist=chlist.Where(Function(t1) plist.Any(Function(t2) t2.id=t1.parent))
If checkbox1.checked then chlist=chlist.Where(Function(t1) t1.vl>0)
chlist.ToList()
MyReport.Datasource=plist.ToList
```

---

These are the result when I press the button :

```
1) With checkbox checked , Press the button ( first time ) - The report  display all the Parent , each of them with only the childs that have vl1>0 ( **Correct** )
2) With checkbox unchecked , press the button (second time ) - The report  display all the Parent with all the childs ( **Correct** )
3) With checkbox checked , press the button ( third time ) - The report display all the parent with all the childs  ( **Not correct** )
```

I close the form , and re-open it.

```
 1) With checkbox unchecked , press the button (First time ) - The report display all the Parent with all the childs ( **Correct** )
 2) With checkbox checked , press the button ( Second time ) - The report display all the parent with all the childs  ( **Not correct** )
```

Why I get not correct results when repeating the queries like in the examples above ?
What should I do in these cases ?
Thank you !

Comment: Maybe you just need to clear the ModelState. Look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856451/display-the-same-page-after-saving

Comment: How can I clear the ModelState ? I try to use like in your link , but ModelState is unkown.